# Solving one-sided limits analytically

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I come to the following conclusion analytically/algebraically:

[image: One-sided limit]

Comment: The expression is constant near $2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has answered the updated question, I guess I'll do it.

Since our limit is one-sided, we know that $x \lt 0$. This implies that $|x| = -x$, and so the expression inside the limit is $\frac{-x}{x} = -1$ if $x \neq 0$. Since for any $x \lt 0$ the expression is constantly $-1$, so is its limit.

Of course, the two sided limit doesn't exist, since the same argument shows that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{|x|}{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x>2$, which happens when $x\rightarrow 2^+$ then $|x|=x$. Hence,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{|x|}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{x}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}1=1$

Comment: Sorry, I initially posted the wrong image. I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok, but it is the same idea. From the left of $0$, $|x|=-x$.